# How to install Microsft.ACE.OLEDB 12.0 on teamcity server

Tags: c#, teamcity

We are using Microsft.ACE.OLEDB 12.0. for Reading Excel data in our automation framework, We are running tests on Local machine as well as Team city server.

In local machine i have installed the Microsft.ACE.OLEDB 12.0.
But in team city server can't install Microsft.ACE.OLEDB 12.0..

Is there any way/alternative plug-ins available to do the same....

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Which version of Excel is your test data?  Is the data simply formatted? e.g. could you save your Excel files as csv files?

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader/

Comment: @PhilS Can we edit/update excel sheet by using ExcelDataReader by multiple threads at the same time?
In Oldedb we can read/update excel sheets at the same time by multiple threads, thats why i sued Oldedb, 
What i did is, I use to read entire excel sheet into data table and do automation testing, and i use to update the excel sheet at runtime by multiple threads..

Comment: Its a reader therefore I don't think you can use it for updating at all but you should check the source code to be sure (its open source)